# how to remove popup on execution of a setup command line powershell

Tags: powershell, installation, cmd

when i start this exe

Start-Process -FilePath 'c:\temp\chrome_installer.exe' -ArgumentList '/silent', '/install'
I see a popup asking to run how can suppress this ?

i get a popup asking to run or cancel
is there a way to remove this ?
Regards

Comment: Is it a Windows UAC popup, or a popup from the installer itself?

Comment: This is probably UAC, and can't be eliminated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without a actual screenshot of the exact popup that is appearing we honestly can only guess at an answer, however, based on experience its most likely because the file is not trusted.

If this is the popup then you can do one of the following things.
PowerShell: use the unblock-file command.
Manual: Right-click the executable, select properties, and check the 'unblock' checkbox and click ok.

Full tutorial: https://winaero.com/how-to-unblock-files-downloaded-from-internet-in-windows-10/

[image]

Comment: yes you are right this is the exact screen sorry i didnt provide it :-)

Comment: Ok i test again its working but  when i also run this :  Start-Process -FilePath 'VSCodeUserSetup-x64-1.56.2.exe' -ArgumentList '/silent', '/install' -Wait  i see the progress and after it open the app why is that ? Thanks

Comment: For some reason a lot of installers use both silent and very silent. You probably need to replace silent with verysilent to get your result.     https://silentinstallhq.com/visual-studio-code-silent-install-how-to-guide/

Comment: hello i try that  i dont have the progress with verysilent but at the end the app open